# How to emit an event that is visible for an other sibling component in marko.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, marko

I would like to create a global component that will handle alert boxes and notifications on my page. The trigger will be in other sibling components

```
<body>
  <alerts/>
  <component1 />
  <component2/>
</body>
```

The code for `alerts.marko` is the following one

```
class {
  onMount() {
    this.subscribeTo(document).on('alert', this.handleAlert)
  }

  handleAlert() {
    // do some animations, make it visible 
  }
}
```

The code for my sibling components `component1.marko`

```
class {
  doSomething() {
    // do some async operation
    this.emit('alert', alertData);
  }
}
```

The problem is that this idea is not working, it works ok when `component1` is a child of the `alerts` component and use the `on-[event]()` structure.

> **How can I implement it in marko.js?**